# How to use promise.all with forEach in javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I am making https requests in parallel for a given list of ids:

```
const posts = await Promise.all(usersIds.map(userId => fetchUserPosts(userId)));
```

This returns me an array of arrays (because fetchUserPosts returns a list):

```
[[{...post1Data}, {...post2Data}], [], [{...post3Data}], [{...post4Data}]]
```

And I want a plain list with all the posts.

Any ideas? I suppose I have to play with Promise.all and forEach but this doesn't work because I need an array of promises for the Promise.all argument...

### CODE EXAMPLE

```
 const usersIds = [1, 2, 3, 4];

 (async () => {
     const posts = await Promise.all(usersIds.map(userId => fetchUserPost(userId)));

     console.log(posts);
 })();

 function fetchUserPost(userId) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve([{ owner: userId }, { owner: userId } ]));
 }
```

Comment: May you share the `forEach` implementation?

Comment: Can you post a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? There is no "list" in javascript

Comment: @evolutionxbox https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach

Comment: But what about your implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you await you can [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the list

```js
let posts = await Promise.all(usersIds.map(userId => fetchUserPosts(userId)));
posts = posts.flat();
```

Comment: thanks, that is what I need